# How can I configure UBlock Origin to be always activated for a specific site?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

I currently have the setting configured to deactivate it by default on all sites. This means that I visit `xyz.com` and then click on the addon to enable it for only that site and only for that tab.

[image: Click to enable the addon image]

If I open another tab for `xyz.com` then I need to repeat this process again.

Is there any way I could add a "temporary rule" or a permanent rule or some other setting to always enable it by default on `xyz.com`?

[image: Default rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to do that in UBlock Origin,
but it's possible by using the Extension Manager of Chrome.

The idea is to allow UBlock Origin to work only on this
specific site, so that in effect it's disabled on all other sites.

Here is how :

- Click the Extension icon
- Click the three-points menu icon next to the UBlock Origin extension
- Select "Manage extension"
- For
  "Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites you visit:",
  set the drop-down value to "On specific sites"
- In the dialog, enter your site and click "Add".

Comment: That was a brilliant idea! I had kept that setting to "on click" but didn't notice the "specific sites" option. I tried it out and it is actually a union of both. Thanks a lot for suggesting this! :)